# uploading to sharepoint library using mapped network drive causes "Access Denied"

Tags: 2007, file-upload, webdav, mapped-folder

A user has "collaborate" permission on SharePoint Library; through the web UI the user can upload documents, but when using the Windows Explorer view or a mapped network drive led to `Access Denied` error.

Thinking it could possibly be a network restriction, I made a packet capture and can confirm no port other than 80 is used to upload the documents.

So, what could be happening? Does she need to have "Full Control" permission in order to upload through a network drive or Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Collaborate" permission level , it might not allow WebDAV protocol 
the Standard "Contribute" level will allow WebDAV.
that would be under Site Actions -> Setting - >Permissions - > Permissions Levels

[image: Permission Level: Browse Directories]

If you have the rights to update the permissions level , you might want to discuss that with your Architect and network engineer / Net-COMM team before making such change.

Best of luck