# SPO 2013 - Open with explorer (Document Library)

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-online, office-365, open-with-explorer

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013.

Our users have been asking if there is a simple and easy way to make a copy of a document in Document Library/Folder without downloading a copy to Windows Desktop, renaming it and then uploading it again.

I studied the problem a bit and it seems only feasible options are syncing the library and opening the library with the explorer view. Syncing works find but it needs to have OneDrive client installed first and some users only have the need to make a copy of a file every now and then (they don't necessarily want to sync the whole library).

We also use mainly Google Chrome or Mozille Firefox these days because IE seems to be inferior browser. A good example of this is that IE can't handle the CSS box-shadows in Sharepoint that well, it leaves some graphical artifacts (gapes/lines) here and there.

This is why I was wondering if it's possible to somehow enable the "Open with explorer" for Chrome and/or Firefox too? I know it might not be possible OOTB but is there any custom tricks to do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE Tab used to do the job for both Chrome and FireFox:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455212/how-to-open-sharepoint-files-in-chrome-firefox
but now it seems that this functionality has been retracted for FireFox:
 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-ie/reviews/

As an alternative, you can try mapping the library as a network drive:

> 1. Sign in to the SharePoint Online site by using your Office 365
>      credentials. Make sure that you click to select the Keep me signed in
>      check box. 
>    2. Browse to the library that you want to map the drive for.
>      
>    3. Click the LIBRARY tab on the ribbon, and then click Open with
>      Explorer.
>    4. Click in an empty area of the Explorer window address bar,
>      and then copy the URL of the library.
>    5. Right-click the Computer icon
>      from the Desktop, or within Windows Explorer, and then click Map
>      Network Drive.
>     6. Click the Connect to a Web site that you can store your
>      documents and pictures link, and then click Next two times.
>    7. Paste the
>      URL that you copied in step 4, click Next, and then follow the
>      instructions in the wizard.

[WebDav](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_made_easy/archive/2013/03/20/map-network-drive-webdav-with-sharepoint-online-o365.aspx)
[Official Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2616712/en-us)

You can do it manually or via command prompt: 
[Map a network drive via command prompt SPO](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116117/map-a-network-drive-via-command-prompt-spo)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! If it works even in Chrome, it would be better than only in IE. This information helped a lot. :-)

Comment: Nowadays, mapping drive doesn't seem to be working very well now. I've heard from some users whom frequently maps drive getting error when trying to. I'm on SharePoint Online as well.