# Map SPO site collection GPO as network disk via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site, intranet, group-policy

Meanwhile I mapping a site collection as explained in this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116117/map-a-network-drive-via-command-prompt-spo) I hit a very annoying issue: I am not able to map the following address.

The url has the format :
\domain.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\sites\Shared Documents

I am using GPO for policies distributions, like add ***.sharepoint.com** as IE> Security > intranet
[image]

This is the script error
[image]

I have check the user account and it is able to access the sharepoint as editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being for this behavior resides in the IE security configuration.
I was using Local Intranet when **I should use Trusted Site**

**Explanation**:

IE Security Zones are used to determine what a site can do... can it run javascript? can it access the file system? can it store cookies? What you decide for company sites may differ compared to what you want for public internet sites.

**What IE does internally** ?
When is given a URL to load, IE performs the following checks to determine which security zone should be used

- If IE has been told (via policy or by the user) which zone to apply, use the setting
- FYI: this is the only way that restricted sites are used
- If the address is not fully qualified (does not have a . in its name, such as .com)... meaning that it is ONLY accessible via the local network (not internet rout able), IE defaults to the INTRANET ZONE
- If the address is fully qualified, meaning it MAY be publicly routable, it is thrown into the internet zone

Next, IE will attempt to load the page anonymously, if the site accepts anonymous access, no problems, but if the site requires authentication, it asks IE to authenticate.
This is one area that zones come into play, and is often why zones get misused.

- In the intranet zone, your windows security token can be shared with the site to attempt automatic/integrated login... since the intranet is often used for sites which are not publicly routable, providing the token (which does not in any way contain your password) is considered safe, and often provides a good user experience
- The trusted zone is meant to allow sharing of SAVED PASSWORDS

additionally, the intranet site is generally configured to be less restrictive than trusted sites, since intranet sites are managed and trusted by a company.