# Net Use Sharepoint DRIVE

Tags: sharepoint-online

This question hasn't been updated since 2015, and doesn't solve the problem: [Map a network drive via command prompt SPO](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116117/map-a-network-drive-via-command-prompt-spo) .

Is there a way to map a sharepoint shared folder to a network drive *without* needing to be logged into internet explorer?

My use case is that I use task scheduler to automatically log in and run scripts. It needs to read and write files from shared drive. It does not have access to the cookies/ saved authentication for having the 'always signed in' option enabled.

Comment: Your linked article is about SharePoint Online. Your tags say SharePoint OnPremises. Could you please clear that out? Thanks!

Comment: I've used UNC paths from a PowerShell script run via a scheduled task without any issue. What errors do you get?

Comment: @JamesGrizzle if you run it under 'run whether user is logged in or not', the drives are no longer mapped, as task scheduler creates a new Session ID to run the task. This new session does not have the same credentials/cookies etc. that are required for SharePoint (it also loses access to all UNC paths).